# iOS4 & background [UIImage setImage:]

Tags: multithreading, ios4, uiimage

Up to iOS 3.2, I used this kind of code to load `UIImageView` image in background, and it worked fine...

Code:

```
- (void)decodeImageName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    [myImageView setImage:newImage];
    [pool release];
}
...
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(decodeImageName:) withObject:@"ID"]
```

... even if `[UIImageView setImage:]` was not thread-safe !

But since iOS 4, it doesn't work any more... Images appear on screen two seconds after `setImage` call. And if I do a `[myImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:newImage waitUntilDone:YES]` instead of `[myImageView setImage:newImage]`, images appear immediately but seem to be re-decoded again on-the-fly (ignoring the previous `[UIImage imageNamed:]` which should have already decoded the image data), causing a pause on my main thread... Even if documentation says *The underlying image cache is shared among all threads.*.

Any thought ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for asking this question. I was wondering why it doesn't work now with my app.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t do it in the background!  It’s not thread-safe.  Since an `UIImageView` is also an `NSObject`, I think that using `-[performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` on it might work, like:

```
[myImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:newImage waitUntilDone:NO];
```

And it’s `UIImage` which is newly made thread-safe.  `UIImageView` is still not thread-safe.

Comment: Hi Evadne, where did you read that UIImage is thread-safe? Can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`performSelectorInBackground:` runs a selector in a background thread. Yet setImage: is a UI function. UI functions should only be run on the main thread. I do not have insight into the particular problem, but this is the first gut feel about this code, and it may be that iOS4 handles the (non-supported) mechanism of running UI functions in background threads somehow differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iOS 4.0, you should *really* consider reading up on blocks and GCD.  Using those technologies, you can simply replace your method with:

```
- (void)decodeImageName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [myImageView setImage:newImage];
    }

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help much. The dispatch_async still pauses the main thread longer than what it should be as if the uiimage was re-decoded. How can I be sure the UIImage is decoded after [UIImage imageNamed:name] ?

Comment: I would recommend supporting OS 3.1.3 for at least several months, and 3.2 until a few months after 4.0+ for iPad is released.

Answer (score 1):

Let's quote:

> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGImageRef CGImage`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If the image data has been purged because of memory constraints, invoking this method forces that data to be loaded back into memory. Reloading the image data may incur a performance penalty.

So you might be able to just call `image.CGImage`. I don't think `CGImages` are lazy.

If that doesn't work, you can force a render with something like

```
// Possibly only safe in the main thread...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((CGSize){1,1});
[image drawInRect:(CGRect){1,1}];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Some people warn about thread-safety. The docs say `UIGraphics{Push,Pop,GetCurrent}Context()` are main-thread-only but don't mention anything about `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`. If you're worried, use `CGBitmapContextCreate` and `CGContextDrawImage`.